# Large image slider as background to main section of website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I don't have a code in progress or anything, but I thought this effect was really pretty cool http://www.twofold.com/

Is there a simple way with jQuery/CSS to create a similar effect?

Comment: That site does it with jQuery, AFAICT.

Comment: Yea, I figured as much. I'm just not sure how to recreate that, using the slider as a background instead of a foreground element

Comment: Look at the source code of the website. It's just a huge 1920x1080 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty easy way of getting this effect working for you just download the whole jquery and the working code from the same site and do the changes according to your need.

just click on view source there will be some scripts links download all of them and add in your code and look how they work its easy...

They are using similar to [Anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#panel1-6) customized according to there need such as they removed arrow and some other stuffs.

There is a same jquery i can say a better plugin with the same effect all you have to do is make it auto instead of clicking arrows and you can hide arrows as well.
all you have to know a good amount of tricks to manipulate

- [Sliding horizontal](http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/sliding-horizontal-parallax/)

Answer (score 2):

These two jQuery plugins are specially designed for fullscreen background slider :

- [Vegas](http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/)
- [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

The two are awesomes and provides full API and docs. My personnal preference goes to Vegas.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any particular reason you prefer Vegas of Supersized? Though AAG, I like Vegas better as well

Comment: I find Vegas API better documented a more flexible. And I like the overlay feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [easyslider](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html)

And put large images in it. As 1900 x 1600, then put your content in position: absolute from css.

You will get same effect.